# Increase RRD step

Tags: rrdtool, rrd, zenoss

We have situation with Zennos that collecting cycle was 30s and we have a lots of data already collected. Now we need to increase collection period to 300s. 
Problem is that zenoss stop rendering graphs it you do it just like that. So we need to increase step to 300s in  RRD.
It there any option to do that and preserve old data and append it with new data?

I've already checked rrdtool options and don't see any option to do that.

Thanks 
Dubravko

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to dump the data from rrd into an XML file using rrdtool dump command. Then create a new rrd with the new step parameters and import the XML using rrdtool restore command.

It's not quite as easy as a "resize" command would be, but it keeps rrdtool lean and mean.

The downsize is you'll lose the 30s resolution from earlier collections.

Another option would be, if you really wanted to keep the 30s information, is to change the heartbeat (but keep the step size at 30s) when you create your new database (you'll still have to export, recreate, and import).

Hope this gives you enough direction. If not, let us know.

-r

Answer (score 0):

```
file=sample.rrd
rrdtool dump $file | sed -e 's|<step>30</step>|<step>300</step>|g' | rrdtool restore /dev/stdin -f $file
```